# Visual Studio w/Docker has exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff)

Tags: docker, visual-studio, asp.net-core

On our new company laptops we are running into issues running containers in docker desktop from visual studio. We tried a bunch of things which were unsuccessful. Any help / thoughts would be great as we are running out of ideas.

.Net Core Version 6 / Asp.net Core (web api)

Running docker compose manually in cmd works and I'm able to hit the site.
Running docker compose debug profile from visual studio results in:

[image]

The output window shows "The program '' has exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff)."

Docker desktop shows the container running but I can't grab logs from it or hit it in the url.

WSL is fine and everything is working there.

My home machine works great and i'm able to launch and debug containers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Faced with identical error, I was able to resolve by deleting VSDBG debugger folder:

```
%USERPROFILE%\vsdbg\vs2017u5
```

After deleting the folder start Visual Studio debugger (F5) and as a result VSDBG debugger will be recreated

Container Tools build properties https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-msbuild-properties?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 7):

May this is not the root cause but just delete the VS (.vs) folder at your project folder it is usually hidden, delete it open the project an run again.

Answer (score 3):

Are you attaching the newly, automatically opened browser window to another window?

Because, if you are, then the debugger runner will crash.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same error when I'm trying to start 2 project simultaneously. And one project was cloned from another. So, they have the same GUIDs of projects in .sln files. After changing  GUIDs  all works ok.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time this error code does not provide any concrete information. In my case I had to go and find error details in logs folder. Log file is generally located at 'YourProject\bin\Debug\App_Data\Logs' location.
There was an issue with 3rd party service and it worked after fixing the service issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error pop up when running an ASP.Net application from Visual Studio in a debug configuration. Bizarrely plugging my laptop into the wall fixed it; must have been power saving throttling performance.