# Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 fails to launch .net core web api

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have a .Net 7 web api that won't launch from Visual Studio. If I do a dotnet run it will launch the browser fine. The debug console only displays the following error:

> The program '[5468] AdminService.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
> The program '[5468] AdminService.exe' has exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff).

There's nothing in the Event Viewer for errors and no other log file errors that I can find.

I've tried deleting the hidden .vs folder. I've tried updating Visual Studio to the latest version (17.5.4) and restarting my machine and VS.

Any ideas on something else I can try?

Comment: Are you using Docker in anyway? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72267533/visual-studio-w-docker-has-exited-with-code-4294967295-0xffffffff

Comment: I am not using docker

Comment: I feel like the only thing that has changed since this error happened was installing .NET 7. Previously I was on .NET 6 and was able to debug (other APIs since this one was created on .NET 7). But now I can't debug .NET 6 apis either.

Comment: Who knows why but I followed the different delete steps in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72418668/visual-studio-2022-error-exception-from-hresult-0x800300fa-stg-e-abnormalapie and now it works